# How to make hamburger visible on click in css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a hamburger in media screen 600px. I added javascript for it to work but it is not working for my website! Please check the code and tell that whats wrong

It is showing this weeoe - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

I just want the hamburger style.display to change to "flex" if it is none and if it is flex then change to none by clicking on the hamgurger div.

```js
function showHamburger(){
    var hamburger_icon = document.querySelector("icon");
    if (hamburger_icon.style.display == "none") {
        hamburger_icon.style.display = "flex";
        hamburger_icon.style.flexDirection = "column";
    }else if (hamburger_icon.style.display == "flex") {
        hamburger_icon.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ranchers&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merienda&display=swap");
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #00bbff;
  color: white;
}

::selection {
  background: #00bbff;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  height: 5em;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
          box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar .logo {
  margin: 20px 0 0 40px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.navbar .menu {
  margin: 25px 40px 0;
}

.navbar .menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.01s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.01s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar .menu a:hover:first-child {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

.navbar .menu a:hover:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.navbar .menu a:hover:last-child {
  color: #f200ff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f200ff;
}

.navbar .logo h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bars-icon i {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.bars-icon {
  display: none;
}

.about h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 20px;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.about {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#2ce61b), to(cyan));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2ce61b, cyan);
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.image-of-about {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.image-of-about img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.image-of-about img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
  cursor: none;
}

.button-of-about {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button-of-about a {
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  background: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Nunito",sans-serif;
  -webkit-animation-name: bg-change;
          animation-name: bg-change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
          animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.button-of-about a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
}

.starting-info p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text12323 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.hamburger {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.hamburger a {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
}

.hamburger a:first-child:hover {
  background: green;
}

.hamburger a:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: red;
}

.hamburger a:last-child:hover {
  background: pink;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-change {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  20% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    background: #22e918;
  }
  60% {
    background: #00ffe5;
  }
  80% {
    background: #dd00ff;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}

@keyframes bg-change {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  20% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    background: #22e918;
  }
  60% {
    background: #00ffe5;
  }
  80% {
    background: #dd00ff;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .bars-icon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .about h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Aviral</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/978a1c194b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/MY PICTURE copy.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo"><h1>Aviral</h1></div>

        <div class="menu">
            <a href="learn.html">Learn</a>
            <a href="skills.html">Skills</a>
            <a href="works.html">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div class="bars-icon" id="icon" onclick="showHamburger()">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
    </div><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="hamburger">
        <a href="learn.html">Learn</a>
        <a href="skills.html">Skills</a>
        <a href="works.html">Contact</a>
    </div><br><br><br><br><br>

    <div class="about">
        <div>
            <h1>Hi, I am Aviral</h1>
    
            <div class="image-of-about">
                <img src="../images/MY PICTURE copy.jpg" alt="Picture of Aviral" id="my-image">
            </div>

            <div class="starting-info">
                <p style="padding: 15px;">I am Aviral,12 year old kid!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="button-of-about">
                <a href="">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You're very close. In your JavaScript you have `document.querySelector("icon")`, but in order to select an element with the *id* of `icon` you'd have to do `#icon`, ie. `document.querySelector("#icon")`. Alternatively, you could do `document.getElementById("icon")`. Always more than one way to skin a cat :)

Currently what's happening is `document.querySelector("icon")` doesn't give you anything, so it is `null`, which means that `hamburger_icon` is `null`, so when you try to go `hamburger_icon.style`, it is basically `null.style`, which gives you the error.

If you're curious, `document.querySelector("icon")` is going to try to look for an element named "icon", just like how `document.querySelector("div")` will look for a `<div>`, and how `document.querySelector("h1")` will look for `<h1>`.

Small tip: You did a great job of organizing your code and making it properly tabbed and all of that, but next time check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) out to format things even more nicely. In particular what I have in mind is using backticks for [code spans](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans), `like this`.

Comment: ok, so how should I make it work, changing it from null to hamburger_icon?

Comment: You would do `var hamburger_icon = document.querySelector("#icon");`. Here is what I mean about how `hamburger_icon` becomes `null`. You know how in math if you have the expression `2 + (5 - 4)`, first the `(5 - 4)` gets evaluated and becomes `1`, then you're at `2 + 1`, and finally the `2 + 1` gets evaluated to become `3`? It's similar in coding. When you have `hamburger_icon.style.display`, `hamburger_icon` is a variable that has the value of `null`, and similar to how `2 + 1` gets evaluated to `3` as an intermediate step, `hamburger_icon` gets evaluated to `null` as an intermediate step.

Comment: So here we want `hamburger_icon` to evaluate to the DOM node of `<div class="bars-icon" id="icon" onclick="showHamburger()">` instead of evaluating to `null`, and changing `var hamburger_icon = document.querySelector("icon");` (no `#`) to `var hamburger_icon = document.querySelector("#icon");` (has a `#`) is how you do so.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple example may help

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu-btn').click(function(event) {
            $('.navbar-demo').toggleClass('open-nav');
        });
    });
```

```css
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Roboto;
    }

    .hero-image .about-me {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        right: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .hero-image .about-me label {
        font-size: 26px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
    }
    .hero-image:after {
        background-color: black;
        content: '';
         position: absolute; 
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    .hero-image {
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: lightgray;
        background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495465798138-718f86d1a4bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
        display: table;
          background-position: center;
    }


    .hero-image .about-me a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        margin: 20px;
    }


    .navbar-demo {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul li {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul {
        padding: 0;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul li a {
        font-size: 18px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        padding: 18px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .nav-bar {
        text-align: center;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-demo button.menu-btn {
        display:none;
    }







@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
   .navbar-demo  button.menu-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: unset;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 26px;
        display:block;
        padding: 23px;
        color: #fff;
        outline: none;
    } 
    .navbar-demo{
        height:100%;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    .navbar-demo .nav-bar {
        left: -950px;
        background-color: #000000d9;
        transition: 1s;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-demo.open-nav  .nav-bar{
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        transition: left 0.5s;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul li a {
         display: block;
         color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-demo.open-nav button.menu-btn i:before {
        content: '\f00d ';
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Meta View Port -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  


<header id="header" class="navbar-demo">
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    <button type="" class="menu-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</header> 

<div class="hero-image">
    <div class="about-me">
        <div class="row">
            <label>My Name is John Doe</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you recode my website's hamburger code please :), i can't change the id and copy paste what you made in this code, the code you gave is what i want just without the animation, and it should have the same styling i gave to my hamburger, to see the styling, edit my code in hamburger selector to remove display: none